# Udev can't create persistent rules, read only file system

Tags: boot, udev, 15.04

After upgrading to 15.04 I tried different drivers for my wireless card, so I thought to refresh the udev rules and deleted the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file, thinking it would be recreated at boot. It didn't and gave the following error

```
systemctl status udev-finish.service -l
● udev-finish.service - Copy rules generated while the root was ro
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/udev-finish.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-04-26 22:11:29 CEST; 49s ago
  Process: 361 ExecStart=/lib/udev/udev-finish (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 361 (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook systemd[1]: Starting Copy rules generated while the root was ro...
Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook systemd[1]: udev-finish.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook systemd[1]: Failed to start Copy rules generated while the root was ro.
Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook systemd[1]: Unit udev-finish.service entered failed state.
Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook systemd[1]: udev-finish.service failed.
Apr 26 22:11:29 MacBook udev-finish[361]: /lib/udev/udev-finish: 6: /lib/udev/udev-finish: cannot create /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules: Read-only file system
```

So how do I make the system writable again?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the file **/lib/systemd/system/udev-finish.service** to include **basic.target** in its **After**-configuration, which seems to do the trick for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy rules generated while the root was ro
DefaultDependencies=no
After=basic.target systemd-udevd.service systemd-udev-settle.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/udev/udev-finish
```